# AJAX'ом подгружаю новости, как лучше

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Собираюсь написать подгрузку новостей на яксе, как лучше:

**1.)** В `php` формировать структуру всего тела новости и все это вместе отдавать клиенту?

**2.)** В `php` вытягивать из базы только содержимое новости, отдавать их в `jquery`( `$.ajax` ) и пусть он уже на клиенте строит структуру новости и вставляет в нее содержимое?

В первом варианте клиент не делает лишних вычислений, их делает сервер.. но больше забивается канал.

Во втором канал чище и сервер не напрягается, но всё приходится делать клиенту.

Так какой же вариант лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от реализации, способов обработки шаблона.

Я делаю с помощью первого варианта, а вообще делайте так, как Вам нравится.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите сказать что на практике эти различия будут вообще не существенны?

если на сайте примерно 10-15 тысяч пользователей одновременно сидят

Comment: @Denis Masster, на скорость отдачи при таком количестве посетителей влияет огромное количество факторов, этот один из них.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше все это дело обрабатывать на сервере, так как к JS-код можно изменить, как вариант, его можно обфусцировать. Тем более, если новостей много, то обработка на стороне клиента приведет к долгой обработке всех новостей.